# How I built a SQL Database connectionstring right?

Tags: html, sql, database, connection-string, sqldatasource

I have a problem with a connectionstring in a html file ... is this connectionstring form false?

objConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=x.x.x.x\WINCCFLEXEXPRESS;UID=test;PWD=test;Database=master"

I need help

Comment: Did you try http://www.connectionstrings.com?

Comment: yes I look there ...but I don#t find a error ;(

Comment: Wait a moment... open a database connection from a HTML file? HTML doesn't have SQL support. There is some middleware technology you are omitting.